# How to insert value in dynamic radio button into database?

Tags: php

Please help me..I have problem on inserting value in radio button into database. My code is dynamic radio button per row. How can I insert the value into the database? Help me. Im new in PHP programming. Need expert help here. tq

```html
<?php
session_start();

$sql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'cpsdatabase');

// Create an array to catch any errors in the registration form.
$errors = array();
if (!empty($_POST) && empty($errors))
{
       $query = "INSERT INTO answer (id, staff_id, module_id, question_id, ans) 
   VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
   $success = $sql->prepare($query);
   //bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
   $success->bind_param('issss', $id, $staff_id, $module_id, $question_id, $ans);
    
 if($success->execute()){
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Soalan berjaya disimpan.");</script>';
     
   }
   else{
    $errors['registration'] = "Tidak Berjatya";
    }

$success->close();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="usersurvey.php" method="post">
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cpsdatabase");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sectionid = $_SESSION['section_id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM question WHERE section_id='$sectionid' AND module_id='1'");

?>

<table border='3' width=900 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1 align=center >
<tr>
<th><font size=4>Soalan</font></th>
<th><font size=4>1</font></th>
<th><font size=4>2</font></th>
<th><font size=4>3</font></th>
<th><font size=4>4</font></th>
<th><font size=4>5</font></th>
</tr>

<?php for ($i = 0; $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); $i++) : ?>
<tr>  

<td><?=$row["question_name"];?><input type="hidden" name="question_name[]" value="<?=$row["question_name"];?>"> </div></td>
<input type="hidden" name="staff_id" id="staff_id"></td>  
<input type="hidden" name="module_id" id="module_id"></td>  
<input type="hidden" name="question_id" id="question_id"></td>  
<td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="1"></td>  
<td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="2"></td>  
<td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="3"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="4"></td>  
<td><input type="radio" name="ans[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="5"></td>  
<tr>
<?php endfor; ?>

</table>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /><center>
</form>
<br><br> 
</tr></td>
</table></center> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the logic of your for loop??

Comment: i need to create survey modul where the user need to complete the survey by checking these radio buttons with one submit button. Different users have diffrent questions. I manage to differentiate the questions based on users role. My problem is now I couldn't find on how the users click these multiple or dynamic questions rows by ticking radio button that have value 1-5. For ur details, i need 5 radio button (1 to 5) for each question per row. Now i manage to click each row radio button but failed to insert the value answered into my answer table in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pressing the submit button the values of your radio buttons will be passed to your `usersurvey.php`. Use the `$_POST[ParameterName]` to get the values from your post.

`if (!empty($_POST) && empty($errors))
    {
    $id = $_POST['radiobuttonvalue1'];
    $staff_id = $_POST['radiobuttonvalue2'];
    $module_id = $_POST['radiobuttonvalue3'];
    $question_id = $_POST['radiobuttonvalue4'];
    $ans = $_POST['radiobuttonvalue5'];`