# How to use while loop to loop a set of radio button groups and dynamic data from database using PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I will make some questionnaire using PHP Codeigniter, my questions are from database. Here my code for retrieving questions and show the answer using database:

```
<?php $no=0; foreach ($this->format->indikator($f->id_format) as $i): $no++; ?>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
           <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $i->id_indikator ?>" name="indikator[]">
           <div class="radio">
               <label><input type="radio" name="ases<?php echo $i->id_indikator ?>[]" value="1">1</label>
               <label><input type="radio" name="ases<?php echo $i->id_indikator ?>[]" value="2">2</label>
               <label><input type="radio" name="ases<?php echo $i->id_indikator ?>[]" value="3">3</label>
               <label><input type="radio" name="ases<?php echo $i->id_indikator ?>[]" value="4">4</label>
               <label><input type="radio" name="ases<?php echo $i->id_indikator ?>[]" value="5">5</label>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I try some of code from previous question like:

[Multiple radio button array for php form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960036/multiple-radio-button-array-for-php-form)

[How to insert value in dynamic radio button into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269956/how-to-insert-value-in-dynamic-radio-button-into-database)

but still can't solve it

when I print use var_dump($_POST) show like this:

```
array(6) { ["indikator"]=> array(20) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4" [4]=> string(1) "5" [5]=> string(1) "6" [6]=> string(1) "7" [7]=> string(1) "8" [8]=> string(1) "9" [9]=> string(2) "10" [10]=> string(2) "11" [11]=> string(2) "12" [12]=> string(2) "13" [13]=> string(2) "14" [14]=> string(2) "15" [15]=> string(2) "16" [16]=> string(2) "17" [17]=> string(2) "18" [18]=> string(2) "19" [19]=> string(2) "20" } ["ases1"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } ["ases2"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } ["ases3"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } ["ases4"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } ["asesmen-1-btn"]=> string(0) "" }
```

My controller is like :

```
    $count_id_indikator=count($_POST['indikator']);
    for($j=1;$j<=$count_id_indikator;$j++){
        $no=0;
        $no++;
        $id_indikator=$_POST['indikator'];              
        echo "ID Indikator ".$id_indikator[$j] ;
        $value=$_POST['ases'][$no][$j];
        echo "Result ".$value[$j];
    }
```

How if I will show data like this?

```
ID_indikator 1 result 5
ID_indikator 2 result 3
ID_indikator 3 result 4
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Without testing your code, Your radio buttons have different names, you might wanna use checkboxes here

Comment: because users will select one answer only, so I using radio. any ideas if I still use radio?

Comment: But you have different names of radio buttons here, user will be able to select more than one option in this case

Answer (score 0):

Well your answers are in the 'ases' arrays

```
["ases1"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } ["ases2"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } ["ases3"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } ["ases4"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" }
```

so you can loop through your post like this:

```
$count_id_indikator=count($_POST['indikator']);   
foreach( $count_id_indikator as $id ){
     $result = $_POST['ases'.$id ];
     echo "ID Indikator ".$id. " Result ". $result[0] ;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. just now, i can solve it , I use foreach in for looping. thanks